# Deriving expectation involving Wishart distributions $E[\bf{A(A'WA)^-A'W}]=\bf{A(A'\Sigma A)^-A'\Sigma}$

Tags: multivariate-analysis, expected-value, matrix-inverse, wishart-distribution

I have a problem deriving two expectation involving Wishart distributions with mean zero.

Let $\bf{W} \sim {W_p}({\bf{\Sigma }},$$n\bf{)}$ and $\bf{A}$$: p\times q$. Prove that

$E[\bf{A(A'WA)^-A'W}]=\bf{A(A'\Sigma A)^-A'\Sigma}$

and

$E[\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'W^{-1}}]=\bf{A(A'\Sigma^{-1} A)^-A'\Sigma^{-1}}$.

I have noticed that both expressions are idempotent matrices but I dont know if that is of any help. I have also found the following Theorem that I thought could be used:

- $\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'}\sim \bf{W}_p(A(A'\Sigma^{-1}A)^-A'$$,n-p+r(\bf{A}))$
- $\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'}$ and $\bf{W-\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'}}$ are independent
- $\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'}$ and $\bf{I-\bf{A(A'W^{-1}A)^-A'}}$

Note that $\bf{B}^-$ stands for the general inverse of $\bf{B}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?